# How to take KML locations and add information inside of them in qgis to build one layer?

Tags: qgis, kml

I have two files, the first one has information and the second one has KML locations, So the idea is that I need to take every KML location that I have in the second file and add data on it that I have in the first file, so how I can create one Qgis Layer that include all the KML locations with their information.

Comment: Can you share these files with us? Both of them are KMLs, is not it?

Comment: No, not both of them, one has KML LOCATIONS, and the other one just has a report that contains information that I should add to every KML location as a table of attributes in qgis.

Comment: Bring them both into QGIS, and perform a simple join (if possible)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might want to do a "Table Join" to bring together a geographic dataset with a tabular data source... something that QGIS and other GIS packages can do.  You'll need to make sure that your KML file can be imported into QGIS, so it should have only one geometry type (points, lines or polygons).  And you'll want your "information" file to be tabular like a spreadsheet or CSV file with uniform rows and columns of data.  Finally, you will need to have unique identifiers in both files, to match the features in the KML file with the rows in the "information" file.  If you have all those things, then you should be able to "Join" the tabular data to the KML, and export it all as a new KML, a shapefile, or some other format. IF your "information" isn't in a tabular form, and/or doesn't have unique identifiers that match your KML features, then can you create a table/spreadsheet like that from it?  You can look up Joins in QGIS, like here: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins.html

Comment: All right that sounds great thanks Christiaan